# Batch file adding to a directory

Tags: batch

I made a batch file and its directory is set to the file its in (c:\users\desktop\batch_files). I want it to add to the directory
instead of typing "c:\users\desktop\batch_files\new_file" I want it to just add \new_file to the end. maybe something like %current_director%\new_file ?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your question, but I think you are looking for the PATH environmental setting. Any command you run from a command prompt will see if that command is in any of the folders that the PATH contains.

Comment: my batch file is not always going to have the same directory but whatever directory this batch script has, another one does also, they move together  like maybe put the directory in between two percent symbols. sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: i want it to open another file in the same directory.but the directory changes when i move both files.

Answer (score 0):

I guess (I also have problems to understand your question) you are referring to not one batch file but several in differing folders which have a companion which you want to address.

```
@Echo %~dp0 returns the origin folder of the actual batch
@Echo %cd% this is the currently selected folder in the current drive
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want to create a new file in the current directory,
without having to worry about the name of the current directory? 
Just do the same thing you would do from the command prompt:
refer to the file *just* by the file name, without any directory. 
E.g.,

```
@echo off
date /t >  new_file
time /t >> new_file
```